# phpStorm стрелка при нажатии на точку

Tags: php, phpstorm

Как настроить phpstorm чтобы при нажатии на клавишу `.` он автоматически ставил `->` (для объектов класса разумеется).

Comment: я не знаю, как такое сделать, но если даже можно, то как вы будете конкатенацию обозначать?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206368579-Type-arrow-when-pressed-dot-